# Runge Kutta error estimation

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve a numerical analysis dealing with [Runge Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). The problem is in solving the differential equation:

$$\frac{d \vec{y}(x)}{dx} = \vec{F}(x,\vec{y}).$$

Defining the error of the discrete gradient:

$$\vec{e}(x) = \vec{y}(x) - \vec{y}(x+h) + \alpha \vec{K}_0 + \beta \vec{K}_1,$$

with $\vec{K}_0 = h \vec{F}(x,\vec{y})$ and $\vec{K}_1= h\vec{F}(x+\frac{h}{2},\vec{y} + \frac{1}{2} \vec{K}_0)$;
how can we pick $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to get $\vec{e}(x) \sim O(h^3)$.

My solution is:

Using $$\vec{y}(x+h) = \vec{y}(x) + h \vec{y}'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2} \vec{y}''(x) + O(h^3) = \vec{y}(x) + h \vec{F} + \frac{h^2}{2} \frac{d\vec{F}}{dx} + O(h^3)$$

and $$\vec{K}_1=h\bigg(\vec{F}(x,\vec{y}) + \frac{h}{2}\frac{d\vec{F}}{dx}(x,\vec{y})+O(h^2)\bigg)$$

I find:

$$-1+\alpha+\beta =0 \qquad {\rm and}\qquad \beta-1 =0$$

I am bothered to find $\alpha=0$, is there something wrong with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong, you have just computed the modified/improved Euler or [explicit midpoint method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method)